# Why did the Darksaber ignite so slowly in Mandalorian Chapter 22 “Guns for Hire”?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, darksaber

Major spoiler for Chapter 22 “Guns for Hire”

> In the end of this episode, we see Din Djarin use the thing in the caves of Mandalore as the reason as to why Bo-Katan Kryze can have the Darksaber. She then ignites it.

Is there an in-universe reason why the Darksaber ignited so slowly on that occasion?

Comment: Dramatic effect?

Comment: Because it's cool 

Comment: It's like a retractable box cutter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lightsabers can be activated at different speeds. Here's an example from *The Empire Strikes Back*:

It stands to reason that darksabers would work the same way.